# Conditional Probability with Cumulative Distribution Functions

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable with a CDF. $a\  ,\  b\  \in \  R$   such that $a<b$ .

Let $G$ be a function that $G\  :\  R\rightarrow R$

$$G(x)\  =\  P(X\leq x\mid a<X<b)$$

I want to write function $G$ in terms of $F_{x}$ , $a, b$ and determine whether $G$ is a cumulative distribution or not.

I started with the conditional probability and wrote
$$P(X\leq x\mid a<X<b)\  =\  \frac{P\  (\  a<\  X\  \leq \  b\  \bigcap \  X\  \leq \  x)\  }{P\  (\  a<\  X\  \leq \  b\  \  )} $$

Then, I know that

$$P\  (\  a\  <\  X\  \leq \  b\  )\  =\  F_{x}(b)\  -\  F_{x}(a)$$

$$P\  (\  X\  \leq \  x)\  =\  F_{x}(x)$$

But I don't know how to go from there. Can someone help?

Comment: Hint : notice that
$$P\ (  a<\  X\  \leq \  b\  \bigcap \  X\  \leq \  x) = P\  (\  a<\  X\  \leq \min\{b,x\}) $$

Comment: Okey, then how do I go from there? I am lost.

Comment: Can you express $ P\  (\  a<\  X\  \leq \min\{b,x\})$ in terms of $F_X$ ?